# Cacti, snmp error

Tags: open-source, cacti

When adding device to "Devices" I get "snmp error". Cacti can't properly connect to device though proper (I think) configuration (i attached png with config). When I debug on router I can see that security level in sent packet is "noauth" and there is no user in first packet:

```
Nov 14 14:03:23.503:
Incoming SNMP packet
Nov 14 14:03:23.503: v3 packet  security model: v3       security level: noauth
Nov 14 14:03:23.503: username:
Nov 14 14:03:23.503: snmpEngineID: <id>
Nov 14 14:03:23.503: snmpEngineBoots: 0 snmpEngineTime: 0
Nov 14 14:03:23.503:
Incoming SNMP packet
Nov 14 14:03:23.503: v3 packet  security model: v3       security level: noauth
Nov 14 14:03:23.503: username: service
Nov 14 14:03:23.503: snmpEngineID: <id>
Nov 14 14:03:23.503: snmpEngineBoots: 13        snmpEngineTime: 386 31276
```

However when I use snmpwalk from the same server everything looks fine, I get information I want:

snmpwalk -Os -v3 -l authnopriv -u service -a MD5 -A  x.x.x.x:161 system

And on router snmp packet headr looks fine (security level is "auth"):

```
Incoming SNMP packet
Nov 14 14:06:58.375: v3 packet  security model: v3       security level: auth
Nov 14 14:06:58.375: username: service
Nov 14 14:06:58.375: snmpEngineID: <id>
Nov 14 14:06:58.375: snmpEngineBoots: 13        snmpEngineTime: 38631491
Nov 14 14:06:58.379:
Incoming SNMP packet
Nov 14 14:06:58.379: v3 packet  security model: v3       security level: auth
Nov 14 14:06:58.379: username: service
Nov 14 14:06:58.379: snmpEngineID: <id>
Nov 14 14:06:58.379: snmpEngineBoots: 13        snmpEngineTime: 38631491
```

Anyone can help?

Device config in cacti:
https://s18.postimg.org/w8aylpsnr/image.png